# best match algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, search

What should be optimal implementation for best match in python.

I have a txt file which has some country codes mapping e.g.

## CODES     NAME

123    ABC

1234   DEF

1235   GHI

124    JKL

1241   MNO

This txt file is big(13500 records) I'm just putting some sample.

Further I have some CDR files where I get country code(numeric) in each record(row) which I want to convert to country name.

Now what I mean by best match is, say the CDR record contains country code "1234" then country name would be "DEF", if it is "1235" the country name would be "GHI" but if the country code is "1236" then perfect match fails and it should fall back to "ABC" since "123" is available.

I don't know is there is a standard name for this kinda search.
like greedy search in regular expressions.

What can be best implementation for this kind search, since the CDR files are really big(upto 25GB).

Comment: There are many approaches to approximate matching. What's "best" for you depends on your criteria, which you are not divulging. Voting to close as too broad; could also be unclear, or primarily opinion-based. Please see the [help] for details.

Comment: Paste the code that you try here.

Comment: @Trimax -- well I'm yet to code for same. I was just thinking of getting an approach. What I have thought of so far is, sorting(by country codes) the txt file contents into a list of tuple. Then searching with full country code into the list, if the match fails then searching the list again removing last digit, and so on. Is there be a better way?

Comment: @triplee -- I'm yet to understand which info I'm not divulging here. I made the question short to address the problem in best way.

Comment: Well, I've understand, You need to work with 2 files: one, the mapping of country codes; two, the source data.  Put the mapping file in a dictionary, then iterate the source data and matches the country conde in the dictionary.

Comment: You are not telling us what "best" means. Fastest, most memory efficient, highest precision, ranking algorithm for ties...?

Comment: @triplee --  Well my mistake,  what I meant was fastest search.

Comment: Build a dict with the full matches and a fallback dict with the last number truncated. The country code dicts need to fit in memory but the main input file can be arbitrarily big; just make sure you only read and process a single line at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries are the easiest way to implement this. See below solution:

1. Convert

123 ABC

1234 DEF

1235 GHI

124 JKL

1241 MNO

to {1241: 'MNO', 1234: 'DEF', 123: 'ABC', 124: 'JKL', 1235: 'GHI'}

2. Read CDR file with country codes and then search in dictionary
3. if code not found remove unit's place and search again.
4. Still not found- print 'No match found'

Below is the code for the same-

```
country_name = {}
with open('U:\countrynames.csv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        linesplit = line.split()
        country_name[int(linesplit[0])] = linesplit[1]

with open('U:\countrycodesCDR.csv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        country_code = int(line.strip())
        while country_code != 0:
            if country_code in country_name:
                print country_name[country_code]
                break
            else:
                 country_code /=10

        else:
             print 'No match found'
```